# VisualStateManager Focus state remains after focus

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, visualstatemanager

I have a WinRT app control template for a textbox. I want the background to go gray when the control is in focus. The code below does this, but when the control loses focus the gray background remains. How do I make it so the background returns to normal when the control loses focus?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GreyFocusTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusedStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="Gray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" />
        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like textbox doesn't go to unfocused state so I just rename `Unfocused` to `Normal` & removed the `Storyboard` and it worked. Below code worked for me.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GreyFocusTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusedStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="Gray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" />
        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: This works, but you don't need to include any content in normal. As long as Normal is included in the same VisualStateGroup as Focused then it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusedStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
```

Comment: I haven't actually. I will once I have a moment, but logically it should work.

Answer (score -1):

you should change state Unfocused